# CopyTo using xlsx files gives error upon opening

Tags: c#, excel, file, input, stream

I have the following IHttpHandler (ashx) handler:

```
public class UploadFile : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite(@"C:\" + context.Request.QueryString["FileName"]))
        {
            context.Request.InputStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Which is called from:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "UploadFile.ashx?FileName=" + file.name,
    data: file,
    success: function () {
        alert("Success");
    },
    processData: false,
    contentType: file.type
});
```

The file variable comes from a `<input type="file" />` and is retrieved using `document.getElementById("fuExcelFile").files[0]`.

This work with seemingly every file other than xlsx. With xlsx, the file is uploaded but when I open it in Excel I get the following error:

> We found a problem with some content in '.xlsx'. Do you want
>   us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of
>   this workbook, Click Yes

I'm not sure where to go from here since it works with other files :S

EDIT: [Here](http://peecee.dk/upload/download/438086) is the file im testing with and a image of it in the hex editor
[image: Hex Editor]

Comment: Probably, it doesn't work on other files either and you just did not notice the corruption. Look at the file contents in a hex editor. Often, you can see some very obvious error in cases of corruption.

Comment: Well considering I can open a image file and view it just file i'm not sure what to look for. I'm happy to change my code around. I just need to upload a file without the need of reloading/submitting the form.

Comment: Why haven't you looked at the corrupted file contents in a hex editor yet?

Comment: I have but I have no idea, what I am looking for. I added a new image to the question showing the contents of the file. I also added the file I tested on.

Comment: Good. The start of the file is ok. `PK` is the ZIP file signature. Let's see the end as well. We might find some excess data there. A common problem when streams are involved.

Comment: Here is the end of the file http://peecee.dk/uploads/052014/HexEditorEnd.jpg - let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong. I'd now binary-compare the two files. If they are identical your code is not broken at all. Not sure why Excel would only sometimes show such a message for identical files.

Comment: I just tried comparing them and it said the files are identical but the file sizes are different. The original file is 80kb and the broken file is 724kb. Why is that the broken file is that much bigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a hard one.

In the discussion in the comment we found out that the destination file is larger then the source. Excel could still open it but issued warnings. This smelled like a partial corruption.

Turns out `File.OpenWrite` **appends** to an existing file. During testing you have appended the same file over and over.

The key to debugging this was to binary compare the files. When you're stuck with a bug and don't know what it is: Investigate! Experiment. Obtain new information. Vary the setup.

Comment: I can't believe it was that simply, thank you very much!